# POSTGRESQL COUNT how many entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, email

I would like to take this table

```
email       |  uuid    
a@gmail.com   1      
a@gmail.com   2     
b@gmail.com   3      
b@gmail.com   4       
b@gmail.com   5    
c@gmail.com   6    
d@gmail.com   7
```

and get the following result

```
email       | count_uuid    
a@gmail.com   2    
b@gmail.com   3    
c@gmail.com   1    
d@gmail.com   1
```

What is a nice way to do it?

Comment: You can search this site for `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Answer (score 0):

Do the `group by` :

```
select email, count(*)
from table t
group by email;
```

This would give you no rows if you want to count of  `uuid` then  use `count(uuid)`

```
select email, count(uuid)
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if UUID repeats in your table

```
 select email, count(distinct uuid)
    from table 
    group by email
```